# Proof involving different distributions in a discrete time Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Prove that if the initial distribution $a_0$ equals the stationary distribution $\pi$, then the transient distribution $a_n$ equals $\pi$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi$ must satisfy $\pi A = \pi$ and the chain evolves by $a_{n+1} = a_n A$.
Note that $a_0 = \pi$ by assumption and the inductive proof is straight-forward ($a_n = \pi$ by the Inductive Hypothesis, and $a_{n+1} = a_n A = \pi A = \pi$).